# ¿Porque no me muestra los iconos de FontAwesome en Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Estoy tratando de agregarle iconos a mi proyecto, en android si funciona pero en iOS me aparecen recuadros con signos de interrogación. Ya agregue los archivos que se requieren a la carpeta Resource, modifique el info.plist y el app.xaml pero sigue sin funcionar.(soy nueva utilizando Xamarin).

**Esto es lo que agregue en el info.plist**

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
        <array>
        <string>UIFontIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-Bold.ttf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-Medium.ttf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5Brands.otf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5Regular.otf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5Solid.otf</string>
    </array>
```

**Y esto es lo que tengo en el App.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <themes:LightTheme />
                
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries >

            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                x:Key="FontAwesomeBrands">
                <On Platform="Android" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Brands.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Brands-Regular" />

            </OnPlatform>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                x:Key="FontAwesomeSolid">
                <On Platform="Android" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Solid.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Free-Solid" />

            </OnPlatform>

            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" 
                x:Key="FontAwesomeRegular">
                <On Platform="Android" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Regular.otf#Regular" />
                <On Platform="iOS" 
          Value="FontAwesome5Regular-Regular" />
                <!-- por alguna otra razon reemplazar Free por Regular -->

            </OnPlatform>


        </ResourceDictionary>
```

**Esto tengo en el botón**

```
 <buttons:SfButton x:Name="getTerminados" Text="{x:Static fontawesome:FontAwesomeIcons.CheckCircle}"
        FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}"
        WidthRequest="120"  FontSize="15"  HeightRequest="44" BorderWidth="6"
        BackgroundColor="Green"
        CornerRadius="30"
        Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="2"         HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start"
        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.getTerminados, Source={x:Reference myAddress}}"
       TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray-White}"  CommandParameter="{x:Reference getTerminados}"
                                          />
```

[image: Anexo imagen de como se visualiza en iOS]

Comment: tenes  agregada la fuente a resources  en el  proyecto iOS?, si trabajas  con Xamarin 4.5 en adelante es mas  facil agregar la fuente  y no tener  que hacer  tantos pasos en cada plataforma. Avisame si tenes xamarin.forms 4.5 en adelante y te dejo el ejemplo

Comment: tengo Xamarin.forms 4.7 @RamiroBarone

Answer (score 0):

Para utilizar fuentes a partir de Xamarin 4.5 podes hacer lo siguiente.

En `assemblyInfo.cs`

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: ExportFont("tuFuente.ttf")]
```

Agrega el archivo de fuentes en tu proyecto Principal (compartido) y cada fuente que uses tenes que marcarla como EmbeddedResource, en la propiedades y acción de compilación.

Luego si queres usarla en un Label como texto

```
<Label Text="&#xF2C0;" FontFamily="TuFuente"/>
```

F2C0, seria el codigo de tu icono, `&#x` lo tenes que agregar al principio, igual que `;` al final.

Si queres pasarlo como Binding

```
<Label Text="{Binding icono}" FontFamily="TuFuente"/>
```

El valor que pasarias seria `"\uF2C0"` aqui cambias el `&#x ;` por `\u`

Si queres agregarlo como imagen en un boton

```
 <Button Text="Iniciar Sesión">
     <Button.ImageSource>
        <FontImageSource FontFamily="TuFuente" Glyph="&#xe805;"/>
     </Button.ImageSource>
  </Button>
```

Si no sabes los codigos de las fuentes podes usar: https://andreinitescu.github.io/IconFont2Code/